# Nhibernate - Unable to query IN operation

Tags: model-view-controller, nhibernate, odata, repository-pattern

Here is my requirement

I have a list of location Ids. I need to return all entities where `entity.Location.Id` in `[list of Location Ids]`

Query used

```
var res = from m in queryable
                      from id in locations
                      where m.Location.Id == id
                      select m;
```

queryable is `IQueryable<Entity>` returned from `NHibernate Repository`
locations is an integer list of `IDs`.

The above query throws an error.

> "Specified method is not supported."

Any help appreciated.

> System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Query.InlineCountQueryOption.GetEntityCount(IQueryable
>   query) at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable
>   query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings) at
>   System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response,
>   HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) at
>   System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext
>   actionExecutedContext) at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext
>   actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of
>   stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of doing what you want is:

```
var res = from m in queryable
          where locations.Contains(m.Location.Id)
          select m;
```